# Contravariant associate to volume form

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, semi-riemannian-geometry

The volume form $\epsilon$ on a pseudo-Riemannian manifold is a top-degree form given in coordinates by $\epsilon = \sqrt{|g|}dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$, where $|g|$ is the absolute value of the determinant of the matrix representation of the metric $g$ in coordinates $(x^1, \ldots, x^n)$.

Is there a concise form for the $n$-contravariant tensor $\epsilon^{a_1\cdots a_n}$ obtained by raising all the indices on $\epsilon$? I have seen that it should be related to $1/\sqrt{|g|}$ but cannot find a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With upper indices, the expression in coordinates is
$$
  \epsilon^{a_1\cdots a_n}
  = \frac{(-1)^s}{\sqrt{\lvert g \rvert}} \mathrm{sgn}(k \mapsto a_k)
$$
where $(-1)^s$ is $g/\lvert g \rvert$ (e.g. $1$ if Riemannian, $-1$ if Lorentzian) and $\mathrm{sgn}(k \mapsto a_k)$ is the sign of the permutation.

One way to think of things is that the volume form $\epsilon$ (a.k.a. Levi-Civita tensor) is normalized so that
$$
  \frac{1}{n!} g^{a_1 b_1} \cdots g^{a_n b_n} \epsilon_{a_1 \cdots a_n} \epsilon_{b_1 \cdots b_n} = (-1)^s.
$$
We can solve this equation to find that $\epsilon_{1\cdots n} = \sqrt{\lvert g \rvert}$ and $\epsilon_{a_1 \cdots a_n} = \sqrt{\lvert g \rvert} \mathrm{sgn}(k \mapsto a_k)$; the determinant $g$ makes its appearance because we're summing over permutations. And since the left-hand side of the equation can also be though of as
$$
  \frac{1}{n!} \epsilon^{a_1 \cdots a_n} \epsilon_{a_1 \cdots a_n},
$$
we immediately also find $\epsilon^{a_1 \cdots a_n}$.

(Wald, *General Relativity*, Appendix B essentially takes the view just outlined, but stops short of explicitly stating the formula $\epsilon^{a_1 \cdots a_n}$. Carroll, *Spacetime and Geometry*, Section 2.8 states the formula, although with not as much proof. Note that the [lecture notes](https://preposterousuniverse.com/wp-content/uploads/grnotes-two.pdf) which formed the basis of Carroll's book are openly available on his website.)